# Django Foreign Key reference object or uuid? Correct way here

Tags: django, database, model

Trying to make sense of some Django

I have something like(left out other fields):

```
class Reservation(Model):
   extendedReservation = models.ForeignKey('Reservation', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Does it expect a Reservation object or a Reservation ID when creating reserrvation with extendedReservation not null/none?

So should I do(reference the object or the uuid?):

```
    reservation = Reservation.objects.create(user=forUser, resource=resource, timeFrom=timeFrom, timeTo=timeTo, extendedReservation=extendedReservation)
```

or

```
reservation = Reservation.objects.create(user=forUser, resource=resource, timeFrom=timeFrom, timeTo=timeTo, extendedReservation=extendedReservation.uuid)
```

Comment: Try it out, and it should be very evident which works, and which does not.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able use both variants to pass a value for a foreign key, if your uuid field is a model's primary key.